# Numbered list with roman numbers in HTML

Tags: html, numbered-list

I'm working on a work file and I have to make a numbered list with roman number in html but I don't now how I can do it. Is there someone that can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS to solve this using [`list-style-type: upper-roman;`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type):

```css
ul, ol {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
</ol>
```

> This solution is working with `<ol>` and `<ul>` lists.

---

**solution using HTML**
You can also use HTML with an ordered list (`<ol>`) with the [`type`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-ol-type) attribute:

```html
<ol type="I">
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Yes. Personally, I would always prefer the CSS solution over the `type` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the type in the **ordered list** tag:

```
<ol type="I">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

This changes things to **upper case roman numerals**.

Answer (score 1):

U can use css for this `ol {list-style-type: upper-roman;}`
See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't enough research about this subject, with a quick google search I got what you were looking for. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_type.asp) it is. (type="I")

Anyway, please make some research before posting questions

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the type in the **ordered list** tag:

```html
<ol type="I">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

This changes things to **upper case roman numerals**.